# Marking a video for adults only when uploading a video via YouTube API

Tags: video, upload, youtube-api

I have a Web app where people (earlier) could upload videos that were then uploaded to a related YouTube channel that my Web app referred to, so that sent tweets would show the video in the Twitter timeline. This was quite successful during the ice bucket challenge a while ago.

As some people uploaded videos that YouTube didn't accept, my channel was eventually banned, despite me warning users to adher to YouTube guidelines.

I haven't found a way to set that a video might not be "altogether family friendly" already during the upload.

Is there a way around this? E.g. by flagging the whole channel as an adult channel beforehand (haven't found any such setting)? I know it's possible to control this manually after a video has been uploaded, but that's clearly too late. It would be impossible to be that vigilant, and users expect that the video is available immediately, without any "tollbooth" process.

Thanks in advance,
Anders Borg

Answer (score 1):

You can always set [video's contentRating](http://contentDetails.contentRating) while uploading.

Comment: It seems to be a v3 exclusive, so it's time to upgrade. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Or maybe not. I'll investigate. "You can read this property as: contentDetails.contentRating.ytRating = "ytAgeRestricted" but it looks like you can't POST this property in the video Resource in the body of your POST request to Youtube API"